# How to handle rest exceptions in CQRS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, middleware, cqrs

In my aspnet core 3.1 project I am using CQRS approach, I have issue with getting correct Rest exception. Instead of actual error I am getting back server error.

My RestException class looks like:

```
    public class RestException : Exception
    {
        public HttpStatusCode Code { get; }
        public object Errors { get; }

        public RestException(HttpStatusCode code, object errors = null)
        {
            Code = code;
            Errors = errors;
        }
    }
```

My middleware for rest exception:

```
    public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> _logger;

        public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, 
         ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex, _logger);
            }
        }

        private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception, 
        ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> logger)
        {
            object errors = null;
            switch (exception)
            {
                case RestException re:
                    logger.LogError(exception, "REST ERROR");
                    errors = re.Errors;
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int) re.Code;
                    break;
                case { } e:
                    logger.LogError(exception, "SERVER ERROR");
                    errors = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Message) ? "Error" : e.Message;
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    break;
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            if (errors != null)
            {
                var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    errors
                });
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Startup class:

```
 app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
```

Create handler which I am using rest exception:

```
             public async Task<Project> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken 
             cancellationToken)
            {
                var project = new Project
                {
                    Name = request.Name,
                    KubesprayCurrentVersion = request.KubesprayCurrentVersion,
                    KubesprayTargetVersion = request.KubesprayCurrentVersion,
                    OrganizationId = request.OrganizationId,
                    CloudCredentialId = request.CloudCredentialId,
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now
                };

                await _context.Projects.AddAsync(project, cancellationToken);

                if(await _context.Projects.Where(x => x.Name == 
                 request.Name).AnyAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken))
                    throw new RestException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new {Name = "Project 
                Name already exists"});

                var success = await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken) > 0;
                if(success) return project;

                throw new Exception("Problem saving changes");
            }
```

My projects controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Project>> Create(Create.Command command) => await 
    Mediator.Send(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your middleware looks ok, but at first glance I would say that probably you are throwing your `RestException` from a async code and it might get wrapped as a `AggregateException`.

Then in your `HandleExceptionAsync` it will not go to the `RestException` case, therefore you are getting the "SERVER ERROR" message.

Could you adding a case for `AggregateException` and see if your exception goes to that case?

Comment: I added aggregate and it is still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your custom middleware might conflict with the `DeveloperExceptionPage` middleware. Can you check that you don't call the `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` method?

Comment: I am not using app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() , commented out and I am using production mode